# Inheritance on doctrine's embeddables

Tags: php, inheritance, doctrine, value-objects

Is it possible to use inheritance on value objects embedded in doctrine entities?

The situation I'm thinking about is:

I have an entity that has and embedded value object. That value object has the following hierarchy:

```
class myEntity {
    /** @Embedded(class = "baseValueObject") */
    private $value_object;
    ...
}

class baseValueObject {...}
class valueObject1 extends baseValueObject{...}
class valueObject2 extends baseValueObject2{...}
```

If I define my entity to have baseValueObject as an embeddable, nothing happens when I use the schema-tool to update my db schema, so I guess that's not the way to do it.

**Another option** that I'm thinking about is to use single-table inheritance on the entity to create a child entity that use one of the value objects, and another child entity for the other one. Like this:

```
class myEntity {
    /** @Embedded(class = "baseValueObject") */
    private $value_object;
    ...
}

class myEntityA extends myEntity {
    /** @Embedded(class = "valueObject1") */
    private $value_object;
    ...
}

class myEntityB extends myEntity {
    /** @Embedded(class = "valueObject2") */
    private $value_object;
    ...
}

class baseValueObject {...}
class valueObject1 extends baseValueObject{...}
class valueObject2 extends baseValueObject2{...}
```

What's the proper approach? Is it even possible to do it this way?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extend one embeddable from another you need to set the parents properties as `protected` not `private`.

https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4097

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your Value Object in field then you should define new type in doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

If you want inherit properties from base then you should use `@MappedSuperclass` annotation http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

You should use `@Embeddable` when you want split entity by specific properties by creating specific entities. So you can't use Value Object as target. According to documentation (I'm not able to share third link).